# Initialising An ArrayList

Tags: java, list, collections

Very simple question, I think. How do I initialise an `ArrayList` called `time`.

Thanks.

Comment: use javadocs for such questions.https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!java+arraylist

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by *initialize*. To simply initialize the variable `time` with the value of a reference to a new `ArrayList`, you do

```
ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<String>();
```

(replace `String` with the type of the objects you want to store in the list.)

If you want to put stuff in the list, you could do

```
ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<String>();
time.add("hello");
time.add("there");
time.add("world");
```

You could also do

```
ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<String>(
    Arrays.asList("hello", "there", "world"));
```

or by using an instance initializer

```
ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("hello");
    add("there");
    add("world");
}};
```

Comment: `ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<String>();` ? Why not `List<String> time = new ArrayList<String>();` ? (Variables should point to interfaces whenever possible)

Comment: But how should I tell if this is possible in the OP's scenario? (Perhaps he has `time.ensureCapacity(1000)` right below.) Why complicate things for such a beginner question?

Answer (score 7):

[`Arrays.asList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) allows you to build a `List` from a list of values.

You can then build your `ArrayList` by passing it the read-only list generated by `Arrays.asList`.

```
ArrayList time = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
```

But if all you need is a `List` declared inline, just go with `Arrays.asList` alone.

```
List time = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
```

Comment: Before the constructor, I define attributes like private int day;
    private double hours;

Answer (score 1):

< 1.5 jdk

```
List time = new ArrayList();
```

gt or eq 1.5 jdk

```
List<T> time = new ArrayList<T>();
```

Comment: This is java 1.4 code. Please use `List<String> time = new ArrayList<String>();` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> time = ArrayList.class.newInstance();
```

Comment: Don't write code like this.  Don't recommend other people write code like this.  It is significantly slower than `new` ... and you have to deal with 2 checked exceptions.  (And since your code doesn't deal with the exceptions, it is technically wrong as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

Using Google Collections, you could write:

```
import com.google.collect.Lists.*;

List<String> time = newArrayList();
```

You could even specify the initial contents of `List` as follows:

```
List<String> time = newArrayList("a", "b", "c");
```